# Bulk delete in node.js json file

Tags: node.js, json

There are some values ​​that I do not want in the value section of the JSON files; how can I delete them in bulk?

Note: I want to delete with node.js

Example JSON:

```
"attributes": [
    {
      "trait_type": "Background",
      "value": "CHOCOLATE"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "eyes",
      "value": "g"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "body",
      "value": "a1"
    },
```

I want the body and eyes values ​​to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

```js
const valuesToDelete = ['eyes', 'body'];

let attributes = [] //your attributes data
attributes = attributes.filter(({ trait_type }) => !valuesToDelete.includes(trait_type));
```